# Any way to make org-babel properly indent noweb tangled code?

Tags: emacs, formatting, org-mode, org-babel, noweb

Tangling this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC C :tangle no :noweb-ref begin
int main() {
  printf("Line 1\n");
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC C :tangle no :noweb-ref middle
printf("Second\n");
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC C :tangle no :noweb-ref end
}
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC C :tangle ~/test.c :noweb no-export
<<begin>>
<<middle>>
<<end>>
#+END_SRC
```

Yields this:

```
int main() {
  printf("Line 1\n");
printf("Second\n");
}
```

I have **org-src-preserve-indentation** turned on, but it can't preserve what isn't there. The code editing windows can't set it correctly if it doesn't see the parts from the previous source code blocks. Finally, I don't want to have to go through all the previous snippets to figure out what the indentation should start at every time I start a new source code block.

Current hack is to tangle the source code, open the tangled file in a new buffer, select all and run **c-indent-line-or-region**, but I'm hoping there's something better than that.

Org-mode version: 8.2.5h

Comment: You could call `indent-region` or similar as a post-tangle hook, I think.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, hooking into the `org-babel-post-tangle-hook` is the way to go. I use the following:

```
(defun tnez/src-cleanup ()
  (indent-region (point-min) (point-max)))

(add-hook 'org-babel-post-tangle-hook 'tnez/src-cleanup)
```